# Hibernate schema generation bug with multiple maps and same value type?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa

Hibernate (Core {4.2.7.SP5-redhat-1}, using dialect PostgreSQL82Dialect) is generating a schema I don't understand, and it is failing when I think it shouldn't. The exception I'm getting is

```
ERROR: ERROR: null value in column "aggregategroupmap_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (1, 2, BILLPROGRESS, null, null).
```

Which is true since I didn't attempt to insert anything into the other column. I don't think I should have to because the columns refer to two different Maps.

This is my main MyClass class.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Map<String, GroupInfo> aggregateGroupMap; 
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Map<String, GroupInfo> computationGroupMap;

    public MyClass() {
         aggregateGroupMap = new TreeMap<String, GroupInfo>(); 
         computationGroupMap = new TreeMap<String, GroupInfo>();
    }

    public Map<String, GroupInfo> getAggregateGroupMap() {
         return aggregateGroupMap;
    }
    public Map<String, GroupInfo> getComputationGroupMap() {
         return computationGroupMap;
    }

}
```

This is a second class, referenced by the first class.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity public class GroupInfo implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    private List<String> groupLabels;
    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    private List<String> groupDescriptions;

    public GroupInfo() {
        groupLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
        groupDescriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getGroupLabels() {
        return groupLabels;
    }
    public List<String> getGroupDescriptions() {
        return groupDescriptions;
    }
}
```

This class attempts to persist Objects:

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

public class TestIt {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JpaTest");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        GroupInfo groupInfo = new GroupInfo();
        groupInfo.getGroupLabels().addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"SKEWNESS"})));
        myClass.getComputationGroupMap().put("BILLPROGRESS", groupInfo);

        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(myClass);
        tx.commit();

        em.close();
    }

}
```

As far as I can tell, this is the problem table:

```
create table MyClass_GroupInfo (
    MyClass_id int8 not null,
    computationGroupMap_id int8 not null,
    computationGroupMap_KEY varchar(255),
    aggregateGroupMap_id int8 not null,
    aggregateGroupMap_KEY varchar(255),
    primary key (MyClass_id, aggregateGroupMap_KEY)
);
```

I tried adding @Column(nullable=true) but it didn't make any difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably unrelated but does Hibernate really have nothing more up-to-date than support for Postgres 8.2?

Comment: I don't know. But Postgres 8.2 is long dead and forgotten and there have been some changes since then that might affect Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JoinTable(name="")` did the trick.

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="session_aggregategroupmap")
private Map<String, GroupInfo> aggregateGroupMap; 
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="session_computationgroupmap")
private Map<String, GroupInfo> computationGroupMap;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `@JoinColumn` property,

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "aggregateGroupMapId", nullable = true)
private Map<String, GroupInfo> aggregateGroupMap; 
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "computationGroupMapId", nullable = true)
private Map<String, GroupInfo> computationGroupMap;
```

Also you should check hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#d0e10955) about Maps. Maybe, there you will find something more suitable for your problem.